# Intuition behind a counterexample to $|A+A|\leq |A-A|$, where $A$ is a finite set

Tags: combinatorics, examples-counterexamples, intuition

Define

> $$A+A=\{a+b:a,b \in A\}, A-A = \{a-b:a,b \in A\}$$

Then prove or disprove the following

> $$|A+A|\leq |A-A|$$

Intuitively, it should be true, as

> $$a+b=b+a$$
>
> $$a-b \neq b-a$$

However, I accidentally discovered the following counterexample by Conway proposed in 1969

> $$A=\{1,2,3,5,8,9,13,15,16\}$$

where

> $$A+A=\{2,3,...,32\}-\{27\}, |A+A|=30$$
> $$A-A=\{-15,-14,...,15\}-\{\pm 9\}, |A-A|=29$$

Incredible! How did he come up with this? (Of course, I can do it using a computer program...)

Comment: Conway is a funny guy. From what I've seen of him, I suspect he just started looking and after a while he found a counterexample. A thing that might help is to try to prove $|A+A|\leq |A-A|$, notice that one struggles, and identify exactly where that struggle lies. With that, one has a big hint in what a counterexample might look like. But I don't _know_ how he found it.

Comment: There is also one point of view, which you don't mention. See that $a+a \neq b+b$, but $a-a = b-b$. So from $A-A$, some element coincide with $0$ for $|A|$ combinations. This is the thing you should also consider.

Comment: @kolobokish But $ \begin{pmatrix} { |A| } \\ { 2 } \end{pmatrix}$ elements coincides in $A+A$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me mention a general result: Theorem 4 in ["Many Sets Have More Sums Than Differences"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608131.pdf) by Greg Martin and Kevin O'Bryant:

> For every integer $x$, there is a set $A\subseteq\{0, 1,\dots , 17|x|\}$ with $|A+A|−|A−A|=x$.

Its proof gives you an idea of how these sets can be obtained.

Note that for $x=1$, we have $A=\{0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 12, 14\}$. Then 
$$A+A=\{0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28\}$$
and 
$$A-A=
\{-14, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14\}.$$
Hence $|A+A|=26>25=|A-A|$.

For a generalization to abelian groups see ["Sets with more sums than differences](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/h5/h5.pdf) by Melvyn B.Nathanson.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @YuiToCheng The proof of the above result gives you an idea of how these sets can be obtained.

Comment: Could you summarize the idea? I just want an intuition.

Comment: @YuiToCheng A general idea is explained at page 2. "The idea behind Theorem 1 is the following. . Most subsets of...".